# unicode mapping for the fonts not available in pdfbox2.0.13

Tags: java, pdfbox

unable to find unicode mapping for LHNDPB+TheSans-B4SemiLight,  Ubuntu-Identity-H and some more fonts. I m using pdfBox2.0.13 version. Please help me find a solution to get the text from pdf with these fonts

Comment: Does it work with Adobe Reader? If not, you'll have to use OCR. If yes, please share your file.